# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I'm testing Java's i18n features and have a problem, I can't load the language file when it's not in the class root. Right now my files are in the `/lang` directory.

Looked several answers here in SO, putting it in a `classes` subdir and loading it like `lang.Messages`, used complete location routing `/Test/lang/Message` (test is the project name), using just `/lang/Message` and still I'm getting the:

> `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name`

error.

Anything else to try?

My file structure is:

> `Test/lang/Messages_es.properties`
>
> `Test/src/test/Main.java`

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

    Locale currentLocale;
    ResourceBundle messages;

    currentLocale = new Locale("es");

    messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", currentLocale);
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesgreetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesinquiry"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesfarewell"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have your locale name in your properties file name.

Rename your properties file to `Messages_es.properties`

Since you haven't declared any package, both your compiled class file and the properties file can be in the same root directory.

EDIT in response to comments:

Lets say you have this project structure:

`test\src\foo\Main.java` (`foo` is the package name)

```
test\bin\foo\Main.class
```

`test\bin\resources\Messages_es.properties` (properties file is in the folder `resources` in your classpath)

You can run this with:

```
c:\test>java -classpath .\bin foo.Main
```

Updated source code:

```
package foo;
import java.util.Locale; 
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Locale currentLocale;
    ResourceBundle messages;

    currentLocale = new Locale("es");

    messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.Messages", currentLocale);
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesgreetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesinquiry"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("Messagesfarewell"));
  }
}
```

Here as you see, we are loading the properties file with the name "resources.Messages"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do have the local names in the file name.
I do NOT want to have both files in the same root directory, that's the whole problem here :(

Comment: My path is like:
Test/lang/Messages_es.properties
Test/src/test/Main.java

Instead of running java -classpath .\bin foo.Main i set it into the project settings, no luck.

Comment: Either copy your lang folder into the output folder of your project or if you use Eclipse copy your lang folder under src then it will be automatically compiled into your output folder and load the bundle with name lang.Messages