# Not able to load property file created at runtime

Tags: java, exception, resourcebundle

I am using `Resource Bundle` for loading the property file to fetch the contents into that file.

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.test.Message");
```

When this Message property file created manually then the app is working perfectly fine but when i create the Properties file at runtime into the same package the it is throwing the  exception .

```
 java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.test.Message, locale en_IN
```

I checked that `property file` exist in the classes folder after it got created, but why it is not working when created at runtime instead manually before compiling

**Note :** **[Already checked this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383191/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name)** Since I am not using any locale So answer on this post not resolve my problem

Comment: Is your new properties file properly closed after writing?  Is the file-writing method holding on to the file and not letting other methods access it?

Comment: Yes it is closed and all the contents are present whatever written into that file .

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
ResourceBundle.clearCache();
```

I hope you are aware that a resource on the class path actually should not be written to as File. It should be read-only, as the classes/resources could be packed in a jar. The clearCache introduces an efficiency too.

Alternatively you could use `Properties` on the File system.